# strsep() doesn't work as expected

Tags: c

`strsep` is not parsing my string correctly. I used `" "` as a delimiter, and it is parsing the string in the middle of a word. I can't figure out why.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#define BUFFERSIZE 128
#define BLANK_STR " "

static char *inputs[BUFFERSIZE];

void prepare_inputs(char *input){
    int i = 0;
    char *token;

    while ((token = strsep(&input,BLANK_STR)) != NULL) {
        printf("token: %s\n", token);
        if (inputs[i] == NULL)
            inputs[i] = calloc(strlen(token) + 1, sizeof(char));
        else {
            memset(inputs[i], 0, strlen(inputs[i]));
        }
        strncat(inputs[i], token, strlen(token));
        printf("inputs[i]: %s\n", inputs[i]);
        i++;
    }
}


int main(void) {
    char *input = calloc(BUFFERSIZE, sizeof(char));

    while(1) {
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
        prepare_inputs(input);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
hi hii hiii hiiii
```

Output:

```
token: hi
inputs[i]: hi
token: hii
inputs[i]: hii
token:
inputs[i]:
token: hiii
inputs[i]: hiii
token: hi
inputs[i]: hi
token: iii

inputs[i]: iii
```

Comment: `sizeof` does not give you the size of a dynamically-allocated memory block. It gives you the size of the pointer.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe it was it!

Comment: @DarkFalcon: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: For a mere 128 bytes, using `calloc()` instead of simply writing `char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];` is unnecessary on just about any platform (other than some embedded systems, perhaps, but even then 128 bytes is probably borderline).  Using the array would have avoided the bug (but not the learning experience).

Comment: Some functions I'm using work only with dynamically-allocated memory strings. Using it is a good learning experience indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof` does not give you the size of a dynamically-allocated memory block. It gives you the size of the pointer.